# Mongodb Atlas "Got Socket exception on Connection To Cluster"

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm using Java & Springboot and MongoDB Atlas and created a database which response to many Object's CURD

When I do the post on uploadingImage, I got this error `Got Socket exception on Connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:114406}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017`

However when I call other object's CRUD, it works totally fine. I don't why it raise this exception. BTW all my CRUD operation of all objects works well on localhost when not connecting to MongoDB Atlas, That means my ImageDAO should be fine, I just used `mongoTemplate.insert(Image)`.

I search online, and they said might be IP whitelist of Atlas, So I setup my Cluster open to any IP Address.

Also I set my timeout and socket configure like this in my .properties file:
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.1c6kg.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority&keepAlive=true&pooSize=30&autoReconnect=true&socketTimeoutMS=361000000&connectTimeoutMS=3600000

it still not work, I think the problem definitely related to the timeout of socket, But I don't know where else I can config

Comment: Is mongodb-atlas-search the appropriate tag Jiansen? Can you share the query?

Answer (score -1):

The Error log is here:
2020-11-01 12:25:34.275  WARN 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Got socket exception on connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:114406}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017. All connections to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017 will be closed.
2020-11-01 12:25:34.283  INFO 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:114406}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2020-11-01 12:25:34.295  INFO 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-00.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=46076648, setName='atlas-d9ovwb-shard-0', canonicalAddress=cluster0-shard-00-00.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-00.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_WEST_2'}, Tag{name='workloadType', value='OPERATIONAL'}]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sun Nov 01 12:25:29 PST 2020, lastUpdateTimeNanos=104428017411386}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-01.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=41202444, setName='atlas-d9ovwb-shard-0', canonicalAddress=cluster0-shard-00-01.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-00.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_WEST_2'}, Tag{name='workloadType', value='OPERATIONAL'}]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sun Nov 01 12:25:29 PST 2020, lastUpdateTimeNanos=104428010234368}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2020-11-01 12:25:34.316  INFO 20242 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017
2020-11-01 12:25:34.612  INFO 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:108547}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017
2020-11-01 12:25:34.838  WARN 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Got socket exception on connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:108547}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017. All connections to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017 will be closed.
2020-11-01 12:25:34.838  INFO 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:108547}] to cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
2020-11-01 12:25:34.876  INFO 20242 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary cluster0-shard-00-02.1c6kg.mongodb.net:27017
2020-11-01 12:25:34.878 ERROR 20242 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception sending message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message] with root cause